# Add new values to attribute of the same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I have a button that needs to add some values to an object attribute. The problem I have found is that I'm creating new objects on every click.
And what I need is to add new values to a specific attribute of a specific object.

I'm getting this

```
Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",  sessionsBegin="1443564000000"}
Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",  sessionsBegin="1443564000001"}
Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",  sessionsBegin="1443564000002"}
```

What I need to generate is this

```
Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",sessionsBegin="1443564000000, 1443564000001,1443564000002"}
```

This on the controller part:

```
 $scope.addItem = function(indexItem, title) {
          $scope.cart = {
              "id" : indexItem,
              "title" : title
          }
          if ($scope.cart.id==indexItem){
              $scope.cart.sessionsBegin=$scope.sessions[indexItem].date;
             console.log($scope.cart);
          }
        }
```

This on the partial view side:

```
<div class="row" >
  <div class="large-6 columns" >
  <div class="panel">
    <div ng-repeat="session in sessions">
     {{event.id}} Date:  {{session.date }} &nbsp
     Availability: {{session.availability}} &nbsp
       <a ng-click="addItem($index, session.title);" ng-show="addMore">ADD </a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: try angular extend https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat a string to your current value, like that:

```
// Add a comma if needed:
$scope.cart.sessionsBegin += ($scope.cart.sessionsBegin) ? ', ' : ''; 

// and then add the value itself:
$scope.cart.sessionsBegin += $scope.sessions[indexItem].date;
```

Btw. usually you'd want a list of those `sessionsBegin` values to be an array - it will be much easier to work with. In that case I'd suggest:

```
if (!$scope.cart.sessionsBegin) {
    $scope.cart.sessionsBegin = [];
}
$scope.cart.sessionsBegin.push($scope.sessions[indexItem].date);
```

Comment: This is almost working... and of course I totally agree: the best idea is to push elements to an array.

What occurs there is that I'm only adding once the session...I need to add a session according to the same times that the users clicks..

If the user clicks 3 times on the same session (on the list) 3 sessions with the same value date needs to be pushed on the array.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand from this description, what you're trying to achieve. Could you maybe paraphrase it somehow? Or expand the example (of what's exacly being done and what is the resulting data structure)?

Comment: With your code I store one session per click.
Kind of this
`Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",  sessionsBegin="1443564000000"}`

What the click has to due is to store the same number of sessions that the user has been clicked

So if the user clicks on the first session ("1443564000000")   3 times the object must look like this:

`Object { id=0,  title="Rolling Stones",  sessionsBegin=["1443564000000","1443564000000","1443564000000"]}`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't changing `$scope.cart.sessionsBegin=$scope.sessions[indexItem].date;` to `$scope.cart.sessionsBegin+=$scope.sessions[indexItem].date;` do the trick?

In your code you redefine the cart object every time you press 'add' though. Hence why your console.log shows new objects every time.

```
$scope.cart = { ... } // this bit of code means you delete the 'old' $scope.cart and redefine it with new values
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
 $scope.addItem = function(indexItem, title) {
          $scope.cart = $scope.cart || {
              "id" : indexItem,
              "title" : title
          }
          if ($scope.cart.id==indexItem){
              var sessionAsArray = $scope.cart.sessionsBegin.split(',');
              sessionAsArray.push($scope.sessions[indexItem].date);
              $scope.cart.sessionsBegin=sessionAsArray.join(',');
              console.log($scope.cart);
          }
}
```